# 'ApplyAuthenticationToRequest' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, .net, google-api-dotnet-client

Im looking into down loading DFA files from Google Cloud Storage, but i cant compile their sample project because of the above error.

Specifically this occurs in the "DownloadReportFileHelper" in the "GoogleApisSample" solution.

Has anyone encountered this problem, and if so, have you managed to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

C

Answer (score 0):

Several of our users encountered the same problem. 
Can you check if update NuGet to the latest version help you solving this issue?
Thanks

UPDATE (11/16/2013):

1. Read my blogpost http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2013/10/applyauthenticationtorequest-errors.html and install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556) patch.
2. Consider upgrading your OAuth2 library to Google.Apis.Auth. Read more about it in our [OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) wiki page. You should upgrade the library to version 1.6.0-beta, all you have to do is installing the latest NuGet package for your specific API (It will automatically install Google.Apis.Auth for you). Read more [here](http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2013/10/160-beta-is-available.html).

Comment: I have done that, and sadly, there is no update.  If there is a work round, id be more than happy to hear of it.  Additionally, i tried the 1.3 dll as well, and that only made things worse!

Comment: The Google.Apis.Dfareporting.v1_2.dll version I'm using is 1.5.0.5, and the Google.Apis.dll is version 1.5.0.28972.  Does that help at all?

Comment: I think that you have a similar problem to this one: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=353&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary. Can you please add some details there as a new comment, and I'll get back to you ASAP. I would also like to continue investigate that with you, so if you can write there some contact information so I would be able to contact you. Appreciate it.

Comment: I have added a comment as requested.  Looking forward to your input.